# Woocommerce product description full width?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to modify a wordpress site with the woocommerce plugin.

I've successfully removed the product image from the page, but I'd like to realign the text so that it's full width, not in a column down the right.

I've tried the following CSS, but didn't work:

```
.woocommerce div.product div.summary, .woocommerce #content div.product 
div.summary, .woocommerce-page div.product div.summary, .woocommerce-page 
#content div.product div.summary {
float: right;
width: auto;
margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```

Here is an example of the product page http://financetrainingacademy.com/product/writing-effective-financial-reports/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.woocommerce-page div.product div.summary {
    width: auto;
    float: none;
}
```

It's aligned to the right because of the float, either remove it from your code or overwrite it with a new declaration.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! Just been quoted 4-5 hours of work to fix this by a wordpress developer! I owe you a pint :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.woocommerce div.product div.summary, .woocommerce #content div.product 
div.summary, .woocommerce-page div.product div.summary, .woocommerce-page 
#content div.product div.summary {
        width: 66%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```